# How can i enable X Frame options in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, x-frame-options

```xml
<httpProtocol>  
  <customHeaders>  
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW" />  
  </customHeaders>  
</httpProtocol>
```

I have added this in **web.config** file and want to allow site for x-frame from https://preview.codecanyon.net/

Comment: According to Mozilla, "ALLOW-FROM _uri_, This is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Don't use it. ... The Content-Security-Policy HTTP header has a frame-ancestors directive which you can use instead." [Mozilla on X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with the below. Moreover, you can check
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) for more details.

```
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM http://xxx.xx" />
```